# rake assets:precompile failing during push to Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, heroku, asset-pipeline

I'm currently using asset_sync in my Rails app, and I have the environment variables set in my Heroku app. When I run heroku config I get:

```
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID:     XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
FOG_DIRECTORY:         MY-BUCKET-NAME
FOG_PROVIDER:          AWS
etc...
```

When I push my app to Heroku, it tries to run rake assets:precompile and I get the following message:

```
Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline
Running: rake assets:precompile
/usr/local/bin/ruby /tmp/build_2pa7aisux9av8/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bin/rake assets:precompile:nondigest RAILS_ENV=production RAILS_GROUPS=assets
AssetSync: using /tmp/build_2pa7aisux9av8/config/initializers/asset_sync.rb
rake aborted!
Fog directory can't be blank, Aws access key can't be blank, Aws secret access key can't be blank
```

But then I run:

```
heroku run rake assets:precompile --app my-app-name
```

...and it processes everything and syncs to S3 just fine:

```
Running `rake assets:precompile` attached to terminal... up, run.1
/usr/local/bin/ruby /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bin/rake assets:precompile:all RAILS_ENV=staging RAILS_GROUPS=assets
AssetSync: using /app/config/initializers/asset_sync.rb
/usr/local/bin/ruby /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bin/rake assets:precompile:nondigest RAILS_ENV=staging RAILS_GROUPS=assets
AssetSync: using /app/config/initializers/asset_sync.rb
AssetSync: Syncing.
Using: Directory Search of /app/public/assets
Uploading: assets/application-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.css
Uploading: assets/application-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.css.gz
Uploading: assets/application-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.css.gz
Uploading: assets/application-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.css
AssetSync: Done.
```

Any ideas why it wouldn't work during the push but it would work fine when I heroku run rake assets:precompile?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can see you're running the assets:precompile rake task with `--app my-app-name` option. Just to be sure, do you have multiple apps on `Heroku`? (eg. staging and production). If you do make sure make sure running heroku config `--app my-app-name` results in the output you had with `heroku` config.

If you had the expected results with the above command, it's likely the `ENV` vars aren't available on git push as suggested here [asset_sync_test github readme](https://github.com/rumblelabs/asset_sync_test_3_1_1) . You can go around that by using the following in your `config/environments/*.rb` file:

```
config.asset_sync.aws_access_key = ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID']
config.asset_sync.aws_access_secret = ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY']
config.asset_sync.aws_bucket = ENV['FOG_DIRECTORY']
config.asset_sync.fog_provider = ENV['FOG_PROVIDER']
```

Comment: This failed in my 3.2.8 app with undefined method `aws_access_key='

Answer (score 19):

I had the same problem on one of our servers, until I found the documentation on the asset_sync github page that says you need to run

```
heroku labs:enable user-env-compile --app <appname>
```

in order for it to work.

Heroku also has [AssetSync documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/cdn-asset-host-rails31#configuration)

It's so nice to only be compiling assets once now

Comment: This worked for me as well when I wanted to get a direct deploy from Travis CI to Heroku.  I use the [i18n-js](https://github.com/fnando/i18n-js) gem which requires `config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = true` in **application.rb**.  So, this command allowed me to not have to precompile assets at all before deployment.  I really help Heroku keeps this around...

Comment: It seems to be called `heroku labs:enable user-env-compile -a <appname>`, not user_env_compile, FYI. Thanks!

Comment: Be aware that `user-env-compile` is retired by Heroku since March 2014.

Comment: Would love to see a fix for this. user-env-compile no longer works. I'm still getting "Fog directory can't be blank, Aws access key can't be blank, Aws secret access key can't be blank"